# JavaScript in webview Android 4.2

Tags: javascript, android

I have an Android app that loads a webpage containing some JavaScripts. It worked normally in Android 4.1. However, since 4.2 it stopped working.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);    
webView.loadUrl("file:///a/b/page.htm");
```

Where page.htm contains all scripts inside it. Moreover, I also included jQuery library. Please help me to make it works as in Android 4.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: Upgrade all js libraries.